# how to round up to the next hour given a boost::posix_time::ptime

Tags: boost

Given

```
boost::posix_time::ptime aTime( time_from_string("2012-01-01 11:15:00"));
```

My function will return 2012-01-01 12:00:00

or given boundary case:

```
boost::posix_time::ptime boundaryTime( time_from_string("2012-01-01 23:45:00"));
```

My function will return

```
2012-01-02 00:00:00
```

Comment: Can there be fractional seconds? Do you want to ignore fractional seconds?

Comment: What if `aTime` is already exactly on the hour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example. I've assumed that fractional seconds should be ignored. I've also assumed that if the original time was already exactly on the hour, then it does not need to be incremented to the next hour.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

namespace bpt = boost::posix_time;

bpt::ptime roundedToNextHour(const bpt::ptime& time)
{
    // Get time-of-day portion of the time, ignoring fractional seconds
    bpt::time_duration tod = bpt::seconds(time.time_of_day().total_seconds());

    // Round time-of-day down to start of the hour
    bpt::time_duration roundedDownTod = bpt::hours(tod.hours());

    // Construct the result with the same date, but with the rounded-down
    // time-of-day.
    bpt::ptime result(time.date(), roundedDownTod);

    // If the original time was not already on the hour, add one-hour to the
    // result. Boost knows how to handle the case where time overflows to the
    // next day.
    if (tod != roundedDownTod)
        result += bpt::hours(1);

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    bpt::ptime aTime( bpt::time_from_string("2012-01-01 11:15:00"));
    bpt::ptime boundaryTime( bpt::time_from_string("2012-01-01 23:45:00"));
    bpt::ptime onTheHour( bpt::time_from_string("2012-01-01 23:00:00"));

    std::cout << roundedToNextHour(aTime) << "\n";
    std::cout << roundedToNextHour(boundaryTime) << "\n";
    std::cout << roundedToNextHour(onTheHour) << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
2012-Jan-01 12:00:00
2012-Jan-02 00:00:00
2012-Jan-01 23:00:00
```

I hope this example helped you learn how Boost Posix Time works.

Comment: I implemented this using to_tim to convert to a struct tm.  I found it odd that I couldn't ask the ptime for its components.  Your example shows me how to do that.  Thanks!